# Passthrough HAL's of Android AOSP

Tags: android, android-source, hal, hidl

I understood that they are 2 types of HAL's in AOSP, Binderized and passthrough hals. According to https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/hal-types, passthrough HAL's can be served in binderized and passthrough **modes**. What is the difference between these **modes** of passthrough HAL's? I am little bit confused here, even through there are binderized and passthrough HAL's, again there are two modes(passthrough & binderized modes) in passthrough HAL. why? or is my understanding is wrong?

For what kind of HAL's do i need to define **hwbinder/passthrough** in **manifest.xml**(i.e., **<transport>hwbinder</transport>** or **<transport arch="32+64">passthrough</transport>**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. binderized mode: The hal have an wraper server, which load the hal impl so, and the client will call the hal by binder. It's the same as binderized hal. It's transport should be set as "hwbinder"
2. passthrough mode: The hal's impl so will be loaded directly in caller(client). It's transport should be set as "passthrough".

From the client side, the API to get the hal instance is the same. AOSP has hide the difference, it will query the manifest, and choose the right way to get the hal instance.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have one more doubt, how can i know that what HAL's are to be added in device_manifest.xml, framework_manifest.xml, device_matrix.xml and framework_compatibility_matrix.xml.

Comment: https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/vintf#manifests-matrices. It's depends on where is your client and server in? In the system(framework) or in the vendor(device)